# Attribute only if tag contains specific string

Tags: xml

I'm trying to learn XSD Schema and I failed an exercise like this.

Imagine having a Tag like "headOfState". It can either contain "monarch" or "PrimeMinister". If it contains monarch, it must not have an attribute. If it contains "PM" it has to have an attribute with the party's name.

Examples

```
<headOfState>Monarch</headOfState>                 |should validate true
<headOfState party="liberal">Monarch</headOfState> |should validate false
<headOfState party="liberal">PM</headOfState>      |should validate true
<headofState>PM</headOfState>                      |should validate false
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

What I tried looked something like this:

```
...
<xs:element name="headOfState">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice>
   <xs:element name="mon">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="monarch"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="pm">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:enumeration value="PM"/>
      </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleContent>
     <xs:attribute name="party" type="tParty" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="tParty">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="liberal"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
...
```

But this does not compile and even if it would, there would be an extra tag ("mon", "pm").
Thanks in advance!